# Showing facts depending on variables

Tags: clips

My problem is that I want to save answers in steps and at the end show results but it doesn't work.

**My code:**

```
(defglobal
    ?*name* = empty
    ?*country* = empty
    ?*age* = empty
)

(deffacts persons 
    (person John Chile 20 3000)
    (person Jacob Mexico 20 5500)
    (person Jacob Chile 20 3300)
    (person John Chile 20 8400)
)

(defrule Hello
=>
    (printout t "Name:" crlf)
    (bind ?*name* (read))
    (assert (step 1))
)

(defrule Step1
    (step 1)
=>
    (printout t "Country:" crlf)    
    (bind ?*country* (read))
    (assert (step 2))
)


(defrule Step2
    (step 2)
=>
    (printout t "Age:" crlf)
    (bind ?*age* (read))
    (assert (step 3))
)   

(defrule Step3
    (step 3)
    (person ?name ?country ?age ?money)
=>
    (printout t ?name "," ?country "," ?age "," ?money crlf)
)
```

**My solution:**

```
(defrule Step3
        (step 3)
        (person ?name&?*name* ?country&?*country* ?age&?*age* ?money)
    =>
        (printout t ?name "," ?country "," ?age "," ?money crlf)
    )
```

But this solution causes the errors. 
Maybe it is better to delete facts after each selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate person
   (slot name)
   (slot country)
   (slot age)
   (slot money))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts persons 
    (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3000))
    (person (name Jacob) (country  Mexico) (age 20) (money 5500))
    (person (name Jacob) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3300))
    (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 8400)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule get-input
   =>
   (printout t "Name: ")
   (assert (name (read)))
   (printout t "Country: ")    
   (assert (country (read)))
   (printout t "Age: ")
   (assert (age (read))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print-match
   (person (name ?name) (country ?country) (age ?age) (money ?money))
   (name ?name)
   (country ?country)
   (age ?age)
   =>
   (printout t ?name ", " ?country ", " ?age ", " ?money crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3000))
f-2     (person (name Jacob) (country Mexico) (age 20) (money 5500))
f-3     (person (name Jacob) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3300))
f-4     (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 8400))
For a total of 5 facts.
CLIPS> (run)
Name: John
Country: Chile
Age: 20
John, Chile, 20, 3000
John, Chile, 20, 8400
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3000))
f-2     (person (name Jacob) (country Mexico) (age 20) (money 5500))
f-3     (person (name Jacob) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 3300))
f-4     (person (name John) (country Chile) (age 20) (money 8400))
f-5     (name John)
f-6     (country Chile)
f-7     (age 20)
For a total of 8 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Can you tell my why it returns False when loading? // but code works

Comment: There's an error in your file. Could be an extra character between constructs. The file should just contain the deftemplates, deffacts, and defrules. Not knowing what you placed in the file or the output you go when loading it, I can only speculate what the  problem is.

Comment: It depends. If you're loading a different program or reloading the same program then yes. If no program is loaded, it's not necessary.